# How to add to contact form 7 options like "select all checkbox" and "show more/ show less button"

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to add four checkboxes to every contact form 7 on the website.

- The first checkbox should select/deselect all 3 checkboxes.
- Second is about the privacy policy.
- The third checkbox is for marketing purpose and should have a button (show more / show less ).
- Fourth the same as the third.

Could you help me with that, please.

I have tried to use show more/ show less plugin but it did not work.

```
<div class="fullwidthcontactinputinlinesmall"><label> Wybierz temat [select* menu-1 include_blank "Kredyt" "Pożyczka" "Współpraca" "Inny"]</label>
</div>

<div class="onehalfcontactinputinlinesmall">[text* text-1 placeholder "Imię i nazwisko*"]</label></div> 

<div class="onehalfcontactinputinlinesmall">[tel* tel-1 placeholder "Telefon kontaktowy*"]</label></div>

<div class="onehalfcontactinputinlinesmall">[email* email-1 placeholder "Adres e-mail*"]</label></div>

<div class="onehalfcontactinputinlinesmall">[text* text-2 placeholder "Kwota kredytu"]</label></div> 

<div class="contacttextarea">[textarea* textarea-1 placeholder "Treść wiadomości*"]</div>

[First box should selected all checkboxes]

[acceptance acceptance-1 class:consentcontactcustomleft] Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s <a href="https://Lorem Ipsum has.pl/polityka-prywatnosci/">privacy policy</a>. [/acceptance]



[acceptance acceptance-2]  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text[SHOW MORE/ SHOW LESS BUTTON] of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text [/acceptance]</div>


<div style="margin-top: 10px;">[acceptance acceptance-3] Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text[SHOW MORE/ SHOW LESS BUTTON] of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's s[/acceptance]</div>

[submit id:submitButton "Submit"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the check box's.. 
You should download the plugin called "Contact form7 -conditional fields"

Description
This plugin adds conditional logic to Contact Form 7.

If you edit your CF7 form, you will see an additional tag called “Conditional fields Group”. Everything you put between the start and end tag will be hidden by default.
After you have added the field group(s), click Save and go to the “Conditional fields” tab to create one or more conditions that will make the group(s) appear.

HOW TO USE IT
Follow this tutorial

MAIN/ NEW FEATURES
SUPPORT FOR REQUIRED FIELDS
Required fields can be used inside hidden groups without causing validation problems.

HIDE/SHOW INFO IN EMAILS BASED ON WHAT GROUPS ARE VISIBLE
Conditional groups can now be added to the emails as well.
Just wrap the content with [group-name] ... [/group-name] tags.

GROUPS CAN BE NESTED
Groups can be nested, both in the form and in the email

Example form:

[group group-1]
  [group group-inside-1]
    ...
  [/group]
[/group]
Example email:

[group-1]
  [group-inside-1]
    ...
  [/group-inside-1]
[/group-1]
ADVANCED
Advanced users can code up the conditions as plain text instead of using the select boxes, using the import/export feature.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you help with that "show more button" as weel?. I need that show/hide button within the text.